# Titanium - Error while retrieving JSON from webserver

Tags: javascript, json, titanium

I'm a Titanium newbie and I'm trying to retrieve JSON data from a PHP/MySQL file that correctly shows on my browser a JSON like that:

```
{"todo":[{"todo":"Some Sample Text"},{"todo":"Hello"}]}
```

I'm following [This Tutorial](http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/91112/Tutorial-Titanium-using-PHP-and-Alloy-to-Connect-a-Remote-Database) using method Ti.Network.createHTTPClient to retrieve JSON.
However I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at /index.html`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong as I only have copied the tutorial code. Thanks in advance!

Below this is the tutorial code:
**index.js**

```
    //Array to store the data from the todo list 
       var dataArray = [];   
       //We execute the function to show the data for the first view 
       getTodoList();          
       function getTodoList () { 
       //function to use HTTP to connect to a web server and transfer the data. 
              var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({ 
                     onload: function(e){
                         var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
                         var json = json.todo; 
                         //if the database is empty show an alert 
                         if(json.length == 0){ 
                                $.tableView.headerTitle = "The database row is empty"; 
                         }                      
                         //Emptying the data to refresh the view 
                         dataArray = [];                      
                         //Insert the JSON data to the table view 
                         for( var i=0; i<json.length; i++){ 
                               var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ 
                                      title: json[i].todo, 
                                      hasChild : true, 
                               });        
                             dataArray.push(row);                 
                         };                      
                         $.tableView.setData(dataArray);  
                     },
                     onerror: function(e){ 
                           Ti.API.debug(e.error); 
                           alert('There was an error during the connection'); 
                     }, 
                  timeout:5000, 
              });                      
              //Here you have to change it for your local ip 
              sendit.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1/test/read.php');  
              sendit.send(); 
       };
   $.mainTabGroup.open();
```

**read.php**

```
<?php
$username="root"; //------------your username usually root
$password="";//---------your password
$database="todolist";//----the name of the database
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost",$username,$password,$database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Can't connect to SQL Server. Error Code %s\n", mysqli_connect_error($mysqli));
   exit;
}
$json  = array();
if($result = $mysqli->query("select todo from todolist.mylist")) {
   while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $json[]=array(
           'todo'=>$row['todo'],
       );
   }
}
$result->close();
header("Content-Type: text/json");
echo json_encode(array( 'todo'  =>   $json )); 
$mysqli->close();
```

Edit, my index.xml file:
**index.xml**

```
<Alloy> 
        <TabGroup id="mainTabGroup"> 
<!-- On click event execute getTodoList -->
            <Tab id="tab1" onClick="getTodoList"> 
                <Window id="readWin"> 
                     <TableView id="tableView"/> 
                </Window> 
            </Tab> 
            <Tab id="tab2"> 
                <Window id="insertWin"> 
                     <View id="mainView"> 
                           <TextField id="inserTxtF"/> 
                    <Button id="insertBtn" onClick="insertData" /> 
                     </View> 
                </Window> 
            </Tab> 
        </TabGroup> 
</Alloy>
```

Comment: Can you provide code that is inside `index.html`? By the way it should be probably `index.xml` - Alloy View.

Comment: Of course, I edit my post right now!

Comment: However, using a test variable like `var tableData = [ {title: 'Apples'}, {title: 'Bananas'}];` there aren't errors. So I think error should be on http method, maybe in some properties of websever, but I have same behaviour with Apache local server and a Remote server.

Comment: I don't understand why the error message contains `index.html`. Do you really use the same code as is above? Is this error from `Ti.API.debug(e.error);`?

Comment: Also the alert message appears, the error message still appears if I comment `Ti.API.debug(e.error)`

Comment: OK, and what about your PHP script? There is missing `?>` in the end.

Comment: No, the php tag it's correctly closed :)

Comment: OK, have you got the same url as `http://127.0.0.1/test/read.php`? If you are sending a request to `read.php` then I don't know why the message says something about `index.html`. Try `console.log(this.responseText);`

Comment: When I write `console.log(this.responseText);` inside `onload` function, this error appears on the console: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1/test/read.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8020' is therefore not allowed access. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last comment the problem has nothing to do with Titanium. Problem is in the configuration of your server ,so you have to look at that...

You can find more here:

[Failed to open remote server file in Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094419/failed-to-open-remote-server-file-in-titanium)
https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148126/httpclient-post-data-mobile-web
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: I've set `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` on the PHP file, but it wasn't enough, as the console prints out this different error `Request header field X-Titanium-Id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`. The final part of the solution of my problem can be found [there](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/156127/request-header-field-x-titanium-id-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-headers#274515) . Thanks 0101 to show me the right way ;)